# Python 3.6 on Anaconda 2.5.0 and Apple Silicon

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I need to install Python 3.6 on my Mac Apple Silicon, but in the dropdown in Anaconda, when I want to create a new environment, I see only versions downwards till 3.8.

If I run this in a terminal:

```
conda create --name my_env python=3.6.5
```

I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.6.5

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/free/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/free/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

Can anybody help me please?